# I can't restart Vertica database

Tags: vertica

I have database in Vertica on 4 nodes (RedHat OS). It was working until I decided to restart my DB. After nodes were shut down, they can't be UP anymore.

I try to start DB via `adminTools`: nodes are starting to initialize, but then they shut down. Using last good epoch or `admintools -t start_db` with `--force` key don't help.

In logs (`dbLog, vertica.log`) I see only one type of error:

```
SP_connect: unable to connect via UNIX socket  to /tmp/4803 (pid=12533):
Error: Connection Refused.
```

It is enough space in `/tmp` and `iptables` service is disabled.

Also I tried to create new database, so it was created and worked well.

Comment: Can you please verify that the Socket file is cleared when the db is down, i.e that it is cleared properly.

Comment: @cohenjo, thank you! But what do you mean by "cleared properly"?

Comment: Sometimes Vertica doesn't clear the socket file on crash- it prevents restarting the server.

Answer (score -1):

kill all processes from Vertica :

```
ps -ef | grep vertica
```

This is avaialbe on all nodes.

Then  start your database without the force option

```
admintools  -t  restart_node  --hosts= --database=--password=
```

While starting the database make sure you tail the logs to capture the errors.

to get more solutions and Vertica fixes see this [link](http://www.aodba.com/recover-vertica-node-failed-start-2/)